# Two arrays in each object - Angular UI Tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angular-ui-tree

Is it possible to have two arrays in each object, like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Drink",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "Alcoholic",
        "subcategories": [
          {
            "id": 111,
            "title": "Margarita",
            "subcategories": [],
            "products": []
          },
        ],
        "products": [
          {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "Budweiser"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Coca Cola"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here you have two arrays, `subcategories` and `products`, in each object. Instead of just the `nodes` array found in the examples:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'node1',
    'nodes': [
      {
        'id': 11,
        'title': 'node1.1',
        'nodes': [
          {
            'id': 111,
            'title': 'node1.1.1',
            'nodes': []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'id': 12,
        'title': 'node1.2',
        'nodes': []
      }
    ]
  }......
```

When using the UI Tree drag and drop, if I drag `products` contents into a parent category then how will it know to fill the `products` array and not the `subcategories` array. I'm not sure how to specify this during the drag and drop. Adding a new item is easy because I can just push to the selected array, but I do not see how the drag and drop would know which to push to. Sorry if I have been unclear. Let me know if I need to explain more. Thanks.

Comment: You need to map your data to the expected structure ...either at server or by using javascript methods

Comment: the innermost `subcategories` and `products` could certainly hold data, but they are not nodes.  You wouldn't be able to move nodes from other areas into those arrays.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping this could be designed so only `subcategories` could have children...which could be `products` or more `subcategories`, but `products` are not allowed children